# Plugin for save config magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am creating a custom module for magento 2. I want to write a before plugin for save function in `Magento\Config\Model\Config`. When merchant saves my module config, I need to send the config data to my external API. If success then saving it to magento database, if not then don't update the magento database. I found this answer but don't know what should I write in the beforeSave function.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109148/what-is-the-event-in-magento-2-when-store-configuration-save

The flow would be like this

```
save() => sendToAPI(config) => success => save config
                            => fail => don't save config
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an around Plugin, so you can cancel the submit. [See this link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

Try [CURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) for the API call.
Just make a simple call to your API's URL. CURL supports sending JSON data, which you can generate with php's `json_encode()` method.
Depending on the response, you can use the `$proceed()` when config was successfully validated and just return the `$subject` object when config was invalid.